# java.lang.NullPointerException .in files.length i think

Tags: java, android

please help me.i write this code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        File dir=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File[] files=dir.listFiles();
        Toast.makeText(this,files.length+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

and it has this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ir.itpro.videosample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
```

i put 3 files in directory downloads .

how to fix it now??

Comment: Have you taken the external storage permission?

Comment: `File.listFiles()` can return null, and you aren't checking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the following permission:

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Also, how are you putting the files in that directory? Through download manager or programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added read external storage permission to your manifest? If not, please add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

line to it.
If the app don't have the permission, then

```
dir.listFiles()
```

returns null, so you call length on a null array.

If your targetSdkVersion is greater than 22, then you need to handle permissions runtime. Further description about runtime permissions can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

Comment: Thank  u  for your help.done

Comment: I'm glad you could do it. Don't forget to upvote and mark as solution :)